# Unnamed app in list of updates

Tags: store, windows-10-mobile

I checked the Store for updates on my Lumia 950, and it shows one app with no name or icon:

[image]

What is this? Tapping the download button does nothing.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have tried so far?

Comment: "What is this?" A Store bug :P. It frequently does this to me with various apps, though it usually (but not always) eventually shows the name.

Comment: @RareNCool Does it happen with the same app each time, or with different ones? The issue went away on my phone after a restart and hasn't happened again since.

Comment: @Indrek Seems completely random for me; happens about once a week on my phone. What build are you on?

Comment: @RareNCool Currently .107 (I'm on the Insider Release Preview ring).

Comment: @Indrek Ok I just updated to the latest fas Fast Ring build. I'll try to watch if it happens in this build.